# Getting null object reference error while using BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I created standard bottom sheet xml file
and I included bottom sheet xml inside to fragment CoordinatorLayout.

after compile and run app

I encounterd this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ourdesign, PID: 8015
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.from(BottomSheetBehavior.java:1479)
    at com.example.ourdesign.design.LowDesignFragment.onCreateView(LowDesignFragment.kt:55)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

i couldn't find reason

this code is part of fragment kotlin file.

```
class LowDesignFragment : Fragment() {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null

// binding
private lateinit var binding: FragmentLowDesignBinding

// buttonSheet
private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior : BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout>
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_low_design, container, false)
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from<LinearLayout>(standardBottomSheet)
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
    binding.include.toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
        } else {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
        }
    }
    return binding.root
}
```

This code is fragment xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/low_design_bottom_sheet"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="403dp"
            android:layout_height="659dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

This code is bottom sheet xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/standardBottomSheet"
    style="@style/bottom_sheet_row_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="?actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_expand_less_black_36dp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editTool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit Tool"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/bottom_sheet_row_style"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/bottom_sheet_element_image_style"
                android:contentDescription="@string/text"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_text_format_black_48dp" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/bottom_sheet_element_text_style"
                android:text="@string/text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout style="@style/bottom_sheet_row_style">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/bottom_sheet_element_image_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/text"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_text_format_black_48dp" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/bottom_sheet_element_text_style"
                android:text="@string/image_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout style="@style/bottom_sheet_row_style">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/bottom_sheet_element_image_style"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_text_format_black_48dp" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/bottom_sheet_element_text_style"
                android:text="@string/template" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: add your xml layout here

Comment: I added xml layout files. thank you

Comment: Where is `standardBottomSheet` declared ? maybe you meant `binding.standardBottomSheet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kotlin-android-extensions` might have gotten in your way. It won't work since your view is unattached to the fragment's instance at that time.

Make sure to *only* create the view in the `onCreateView(...)` method, and use it in `onViewCreated(...)`. It's called immediately afterwards so you won't lose any time and the fragment won't start uninitialized.

Your code would ideally look like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentLowDesignBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_low_design, container, false)
    .also { binding = it }
    .root

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from<LinearLayout>(binding.standardBottomSheet)
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
    binding.include.toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
        } else {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
        }
    }
    // continue
}
```

---

If you'd like to bypass all of that boilerplate, feel free to use [teanity](https://github.com/skoumalcz/teanity/tree/1.2/core) :) It makes these things really simple.

Comment: It still doesn't work....
Is it possible implement bottom sheet in fragment class file?
Every example code is implement standard bottom sheet in activity class file. I can't find example code.

Comment: Yes of course. As long as both CoordinatorLayout and given BottomSheetBehavior are in the same xml. BottomSheetBehavior should be direct child of CoordinatorLayout in every case.

Comment: Did you meean direct child of CoordinatorLayout mean use dierctly inside the CoordinatorLayout instead using include tag?
and...
so. if i want to use bottom sheet. not in main activity.
Should i have to create another activity and fragment?
Thank you for helping me even though it's a low-level question..!

Comment: Yes it has to be the direct child of the given CoordinatorLayout, otherwise it **will not** work. The include tag will work but you have to structure it in a way where the include is **inside** the View that has the BottomSheetBehavior on it.

If you need to use bottom sheets outside of your root activity then is probably a good idea to create a BottomSheetDialog. Having it in both your root activity *and* a fragment will not do any good.